# How to replace list item in best way

Tags: c#

```
if (listofelements.Contains(valueFieldValue.ToString()))
{
    listofelements[listofelements.IndexOf(valueFieldValue.ToString())] = value.ToString();
}
```

I have replaced like above.  Is there any other bestway to place compare than this one?

Answer (score 233, accepted):

Use Lambda to find the index in the List and use this index to replace the list item.

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string> { "abc", "123", "ghi" };

int index = listOfStrings.FindIndex(s => s == "123");

if (index != -1)
    listOfStrings[index] =  "def";
```

Comment: Check for -1 ! Incase the item is not present in collections

Comment: plus one for use of FindIndex

Comment: This is the best universal answer IMHO since this can be used to compare objects as well.

Comment: See [Fej's enhancement that checks for -1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46361200/199364). Though for a simple `Equals` test, good old `IndexOf` works just as well, and is more concise - as in [Tim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17189025/199364).

Comment: do you know a way to implement that on more then one value each time?

Answer (score 130):

You could make it more readable and more efficient:

```
string oldValue = valueFieldValue.ToString();
string newValue = value.ToString();
int index = listofelements.IndexOf(oldValue);
if(index != -1)
    listofelements[index] = newValue;
```

This asks only once for the index. Your approach uses `Contains` first which needs to loop all items(in the worst case), then you're using `IndexOf` which needs to enumerate the items again .

Comment: This is the correct answer for finding literals - ints, strings, but not very good for finding objects. However, I like rokkuchan's answer better since it's universal.

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky: does work also with reference types, the type just needs to override `Equals` or you will only find the object if it's the same reference. Note that `string` is also an object (reference type).

Comment: Yes you are right. However, I have seen many developers failing to remember to implement `Equals ` and you also have to remember that sometimes at the same time you have to implement `GetHashCode`

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky: yes, you should always override `GetHashCode` if you override `Equals` but `GetHashCode` is only used if the object is stored in a set(f.e. `Dictionary` or `HashSet`), so it's not used with `IndexOf` or `Contains`, only `Equals`.

Comment: Tim, I have a question about this vs rokkuchan. I read in docs that `IndexOf` uses `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`. Are you saying that will eventually call `item.Equals(target)` for each item in the list, and therefore has the exact same behavior as rokkuchan's answer?

Answer (score 23):

Why not use the extension methods?

Consider the following code:

```
        var intArray = new int[] { 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4 };
        // Replaces the first occurance and returns the index
        var index = intArray.Replace(1, 0);
        // {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4}; index=1

        var stringList = new List<string> { "a", "a", "c", "d"};
        stringList.ReplaceAll("a", "b");
        // {"b", "b", "c", "d"};

        var intEnum = intArray.Select(x => x);
        intEnum = intEnum.Replace(0, 1);
        // {0, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4} => {1, 1, 1, 2, 3, 4}
```

- No code duplication
- There is no need to type long linq expressions
- There is no need for additional usings

The source code:

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static int Replace<T>(this IList<T> source, T oldValue, T newValue)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

            var index = source.IndexOf(oldValue);
            if (index != -1)
                source[index] = newValue;
            return index;
        }

        public static void ReplaceAll<T>(this IList<T> source, T oldValue, T newValue)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

            int index = -1;
            do
            {
                index = source.IndexOf(oldValue);
                if (index != -1)
                    source[index] = newValue;
            } while (index != -1);
        }


        public static IEnumerable<T> Replace<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, T oldValue, T newValue)
        {
            if (source == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));

            return source.Select(x => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, oldValue) ? newValue : x);
        }
    }
}
```

The first two methods have been added to change the objects of reference types in place. Of course, you can use just the third method for all types.

P.S. Thanks to [mike's observation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40775481/6550259), I've added the ReplaceAll method.

Comment: Re *"change the objects of reference types in place"* - whether `T` is a reference type or not is irrelevant. What matters is whether you want to mutate (alter) the list, or return a new list. The third method of course won't alter the original list, so you **can't** *use just the third method...*. The first method is the one that answers the specific question asked. Excellent code - just correcting your description of what the methods do :)

Answer (score 17):

You are accessing your list twice to replace one element. I think simple `for` loop should be enough:

```
var key = valueFieldValue.ToString();
for (int i = 0; i < listofelements.Count; i++)
{
    if (listofelements[i] == key)
    {
        listofelements[i] = value.ToString();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: @gzaxx. "You are accessing your list twice to replace one element. I think simple for loop should be enough". And how many times do you access the list in your for loop mate?

Comment: @Pap sorry, I was not being clear enough. He is iterating his list twice (first to check if item is inside the list, second to get item index).

Answer (score 10):

Following rokkuchan's answer, just a little upgrade:

```
List<string> listOfStrings = new List<string> {"abc", "123", "ghi"};

int index = listOfStrings.FindIndex(ind => ind.Equals("123"));
if (index > -1)
    listOfStrings[index] =  "def";
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the next extensions which are based on a predicate condition:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Find an index of a first element that satisfies <paramref name="match"/>
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of elements in the source collection</typeparam>
    /// <param name="this">This</param>
    /// <param name="match">Match predicate</param>
    /// <returns>Zero based index of an element. -1 if there is not such matches</returns>
    public static int IndexOf<T>(this IList<T> @this, Predicate<T> match)
    {
        @this.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull();
        match.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull();

        for (int i = 0; i < @this.Count; ++i)
            if (match(@this[i]))
                return i;

        return -1;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace the first occurance of an oldValue which satisfies the <paramref name="removeByCondition"/> by a newValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of elements of a target list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="this">Source collection</param>
    /// <param name="removeByCondition">A condition which decides is a value should be replaced or not</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">A new value instead of replaced</param>
    /// <returns>This</returns>
    public static IList<T> Replace<T>(this IList<T> @this, Predicate<T> replaceByCondition, T newValue)
    {
        @this.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull();
        removeByCondition.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull();

        int index = @this.IndexOf(replaceByCondition);
        if (index != -1)
            @this[index] = newValue;

        return @this;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Replace all occurance of values which satisfy the <paramref name="removeByCondition"/> by a newValue
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Type of elements of a target list</typeparam>
    /// <param name="this">Source collection</param>
    /// <param name="removeByCondition">A condition which decides is a value should be replaced or not</param>
    /// <param name="newValue">A new value instead of replaced</param>
    /// <returns>This</returns>
    public static IList<T> ReplaceAll<T>(this IList<T> @this, Predicate<T> replaceByCondition, T newValue)
    {
        @this.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull();
        removeByCondition.ThrowIfArgumentIsNull();

        for (int i = 0; i < @this.Count; ++i)
            if (replaceByCondition(@this[i]))
                @this[i] = newValue;

        return @this;
    }
```

Notes:
 - Instead of ThrowIfArgumentIsNull extension, you can use a general approach like:

```
if (argName == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(argName));
```

So your case with these extensions can be solved as:

```
string targetString = valueFieldValue.ToString();
listofelements.Replace(x => x.Equals(targetString), value.ToString());
```

Comment: This is a useful example.

Answer (score 4):

Use `FindIndex` and lambda to find and replace your values:

```
int j = listofelements.FindIndex(i => i.Contains(valueFieldValue.ToString())); //Finds the item index

lstString[j] = lstString[j].Replace(valueFieldValue.ToString(), value.ToString()); //Replaces the item by new value
```

Comment: it replace part of string in first occurrence and set resoult to list item...

Answer (score 4):

You can use lambda expression like this.

```
int index = listOfElements.FindIndex(item => item.Id == id);  
if (index != -1) 
{
    listOfElements[index] = newValue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't if it is best or not but you can use it also

```
List<string> data = new List<string>
(new string[]   { "Computer", "A", "B", "Computer", "B", "A" });
int[] indexes = Enumerable.Range(0, data.Count).Where
                 (i => data[i] == "Computer").ToArray();
Array.ForEach(indexes, i => data[i] = "Calculator");
```

Answer (score 1):

Or, building on Rusian L.'s suggestion, if the item you're searching for can be in the list more than once::

```
[Extension()]
public void ReplaceAll<T>(List<T> input, T search, T replace)
{
    int i = 0;
    do {
        i = input.FindIndex(i, s => EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(s, search));

        if (i > -1) {
            FileSystem.input(i) = replace;
            continue;
        }

        break;  
    } while (true);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

i find best for do it fast and simple

1. find ur item in list

   ```
   var d = Details.Where(x => x.ProductID == selectedProduct.ID).SingleOrDefault();
   ```
2. make clone from current

   ```
   OrderDetail dd = d;
   ```
3. Update ur clone

   ```
   dd.Quantity++;
   ```
4. find index in list

   ```
   int idx = Details.IndexOf(d);
   ```
5. remove founded item in (1)

   ```
     Details.Remove(d);
   ```
6. insert

   ```
    if (idx > -1)
         Details.Insert(idx, dd);
     else
         Details.Insert(Details.Count, dd);
   ```

Comment: "OrderDetail dd = d;" doesn't clone, it copies reference.

Answer (score -1):

```
//with multiple replacements - NOT USING FOREACH 
for(x=0;x<listOfElements.Count;x++)
{

    int i= listOfElements.IndexOf(oldvalue);

    listOfElements.Insert(i, newvalue);
    listOfElments.RemoveAt(i+1);
}
```

Comment: Insert and remove are definitely not a way to go cause it can result in resizing of the underlying array.

Comment: Even if it doesn't resize, it will move all elements after i twice.

Comment: If you use it inside a foreach cicle , what you say  is true. But if you use it inside a for (x=0; x<listOfElements.Count ;x++), that is a viable solution.