# Replace an object in a list of objects

Tags: c#, .net, list, variable-assignment, generic-list

In C#, if I have a `List<T>`, and I have an object of type `T`, how can I replace a specific item in the `List<T>` with the object of type `T`?

Here is what I have tried:

```
List<CustomListItem> customListItems = new List<CustomListItem>();
CustomListItem customListItem1 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 1", date = DateTime.MinValue};
CustomListItem customListItem2 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 2", date = DateTime.MinValue };
CustomListItem customListItem3 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 3", date = DateTime.MinValue };

customListItems.Add(customListItem1);
customListItems.Add(customListItem2);
customListItems.Add(customListItem3);

CustomListItem newCustomListItem = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 4", date = DateTime.Now };

customListItem2 = customListItems.Where(i=> i.name == "Item 2").First();
customListItem2 = newCustomListItem;
```

In the above code, I want to replace the `customListItem2` with the `newCustomListItem`.

Do I have to remove the item in the list, and then insert the new item? Can I not do a simple assignment of `customListItem2 = newCustomListItem`?

What is the most efficient way of replacing an item in a list with another item?

Comment: Have you checked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188966/how-to-replace-list-item-in-best-way?

Comment: Additional to the solutions that have already been posted you should also implement an Equals/GetHashCode for your custom type, otherwise your Where/Index-operation may fail to find the right element.

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You have to replace the item, not the value of `customListItem2`. Just replace following:

```
customListItem2 = customListItems.Where(i=> i.name == "Item 2").First();
customListItem2 = newCustomListItem;
```

With this:

```
customListItem2 = customListItems.Where(i=> i.name == "Item 2").First();
var index = customListItems.IndexOf(customListItem2);

if(index != -1)
    customListItems[index] = newCustomListItem;
```

**Edit:**

As [Roman R.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752909/replace-a-object-in-a-list-of-objects/26752977?noredirect=1#comment63906297_26752977) stated in a comment, you can replace the  `.Where(predicate).First()` by a simple `First(predicate)`:

```
customListItem2 = customListItems.First(i=> i.name == "Item 2");
```

Comment: You can replace the .Where with .First in the first place and delete it from the end. It will be the same result but with cleaner and faster code. Do it like the following: customListItem2 = customListItems.First(i=> i.name == "Item 2");

Comment: Using this code, is it possible that the index will be -1? After all, if it wasn't on the list, First() would throw an error first :)

Comment: then use `FirstOrDefault()` which will return null if not found, then -1 for the `IndexOf(null)`

Comment: @RomanR. - It will make it only cleaner; it's already proven that `First(expresion)` is slower than `Where(expresion).First()`. Useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8663897/why-is-linq-wherepredicate-first-faster-than-firstpredicate

Comment: @HellBaby seems to be outdated. Have a look at this https://dotnetfiddle.net/OrUUSG Tried it myself and verified the results.

Comment: EDIT: Depends on the parameters your passing. Change n to 90 and First without Where is slower...

Comment: @HellBaby interesting observation - visual studio will try to underline it and suggest that you make it .First instead of .Where().First though despite the slowness

Answer (score 13):

```
var customListItems = new List<CustomListItem>();
var customListItem1 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 1", date = DateTime.MinValue };
var customListItem2 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 2", date = DateTime.MinValue };
var customListItem3 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 3", date = DateTime.MinValue };

customListItems.Add(customListItem1);
customListItems.Add(customListItem2);
customListItems.Add(customListItem3);

var newCustomListItem = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 4", date = DateTime.Now };

customListItems[customListItems.FindIndex(x => x.name == "Item 2")] = newCustomListItem;
```

or

```
public static class ListExtensions
{
    public static void Replace<T>(this List<T> list, Predicate<T> oldItemSelector , T newItem)
    {
        //check for different situations here and throw exception
        //if list contains multiple items that match the predicate
        //or check for nullability of list and etc ...
        var oldItemIndex = list.FindIndex(oldItemSelector);
        list[oldItemIndex] = newItem;
    }
}
```

and then

```
customListItems.Replace(x => x.name == "Item 2", newCustomListItem);
```

Comment: Does the extension approach use reflection? It is certainly more convenient with this code, and I went this route. Just wondering about any performance hit.

Comment: No, it does not use reflection. @dunwan

Comment: With this solution the list is only looped once. With the one in the accepted answer twice. But often or usually the not-found-case should be handled. If the item is not found FindIndex returns -1.

Answer (score 0):

if sequence of list not matter to you then
you can try this

```
CustomListItem newCustomListItem = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 4", date = DateTime.Now };

customListItem2 = customListItems.Where(i=> i.name == "Item 2").First();  

customListItems.Remove(customListItem2);
customListItems.Add(newCustomListItem );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a select to build a new iEnumerable with replace item :

```
customListItems.Select(x => x.name == "Item 2" ? newItem : x).ToList();
```

i did not test for performance but I found this solution quite concise and explicit.

Answer (score -2):

An alternative would be to use the `DynamicData` package that has lot of others facilities on lists:

**Quick Answer**

make sure the package is installed:

```cs
Install-Package DynamicData -Version 7.4.3
```

then

```cs
using DynamicData;

DynamicData.ListEx.Replace<CustomListItem>(customListItems, customListItem2, newCustomListItem);
```

The following is the complete working solution.

**Working Example**

my custom item class

```cs
public class CustomListItem
{
    public string name; 
    public DateTime date;

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return name + ", " + date.ToString();
    }
}
```

In the main try this, make sure to comment out the assignment before the replacement.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<CustomListItem> customListItems = new List<CustomListItem>();
    CustomListItem customListItem1 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 1", date = DateTime.MinValue };
    CustomListItem customListItem2 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 2", date = DateTime.MinValue };
    CustomListItem customListItem3 = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 3", date = DateTime.MinValue };

    customListItems.Add(customListItem1);
    customListItems.Add(customListItem2);
    customListItems.Add(customListItem3);

    CustomListItem newCustomListItem = new CustomListItem() { name = "Item 4", date = DateTime.Now };

    customListItem2 = customListItems.Where(i => i.name == "Item 2").First();
    //customListItem2 = newCustomListItem;


    DynamicData.ListEx.Replace<CustomListItem>(customListItems, customListItem2, newCustomListItem);

    foreach(var customListItem in customListItems)
    {
        Debug.Print("\n" + customListItem.ToString());
    }
}

references: https://github.com/reactivemarbles/DynamicData.
https://dynamic-data.org
```

Answer (score -2):

I normally have some basic interfaces that define a key field so that I can use generics more easily.  So classes that inherit IKey will have a string Key field that is a unique identifier to the record.

So building ontop of Hamid's example but with a 'add or replace' concept:

```
    public static void AddOrReplace<T>(this List<T> items, T newItem) where T : class, IKey
    {
        items.AddOrReplace(x => x.Key == newItem.Key, newItem);
    }

    public static void AddOrReplace<T>(this List<T> items, Predicate<T> oldItemSelector, T newItem)
    {            
        var index = items.FindIndex(oldItemSelector);
        if (index < 0)
        {
            items.Add(newItem);
        }
        else
        {
            items[index] = newItem;
        }            
    }
```

Then to implement these extensions I can use a similar syntax to the list.Add():

```
list.AddOrReplace(newItem);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).