# Compare Two Lists Via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have two lists will say ListA and ListB.  I need to loop through ListB and compare ID's to ListA.  If there is a match then I need to remove that item from ListB and replace it with the matching item/object from ListA.

I've been looking at [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26752909/replace-a-object-in-a-list-of-objects) article. I've also had a look at Intersect. But I'm really not sure on how to get this to work with Linq.

Here is my code:

ListB is a query generated else where and passed  in

```
var itemsForListA = Context.Set<Item>().AsQueryable();
var ListA = from i in itemsForListA 
            where i.ReplacementItemID != null
                  && (i.ItemStatus == "DISC" || i.ItemStatus == "ACT" 
                  && i.StoreID == null)
            select i;

foreach (var i in ListB)
{
    ListB = ListA.Where(x => x.Id == ListA.Id);
}
```

I thought I could do something like that.  Do I first have to find the id in ListB and remove it then append on the new id from ListA to B?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I thought you can use left join in linq as below.

```
var list = from lb in ListB
    join la in ListA
        on lb.Id equals la.Id into ListC
    from lc in ListC.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select lc ?? lb;
```

It won't remove and replace the items, but it will give the same result and you can reassign to `ListB`

Comment: `select obj = la ?? lb` is enough (assuming that the items in both lists are the same types). This shouldn't have a downvote.

Comment: Scott Hannen did some [excellent testing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38643794/compare-two-lists-via-linq/38647014#comment64678247_38647014) revealing that this method is not bad at all.

Comment: Thanks Gert Arnold

Answer (score 1):

Use the built in [`Enumerable.Except()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx) method using the `IEqualityComparer`.

Class to compare

```
public class Item
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comparer

```
public class ItemIdComparer<Item>
{
  public bool Equals(Item left, Item right)
  {
    return left.Id == right.Id;
  }
  public int GetHashCode(Item item)
  {
    return item.Id.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Usage

```
var all = new List<Item>();
var existing = new List<Item>();

var nonExisting = all.Except(existing, new ItemIdComparer())
```

I can't test this exactly... but it should be very close.

Answer (score 0):

you can do as follow:

```
var list = listB.Join(listA, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, y) => y).ToList();

list.AddRange(listB.Where(b => listA.Any(c => c.Id != b.Id)).ToList());
```

1. First, I compare the listA with listB and selected objects from listA with same ID.
2. to the selected objects I add it the elements from listB which have no comon id with listA.

Comment: y.Id has this error "Error CS1061 'int' does not contain a definition for 'Id' and no extension method 'Id' accepting a first argument of type 'int' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: you said that the compare must be done by Id, to do so, you need to have the id prop, in both list objects

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how your *model* looks like, so I created my own model:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FullName { get; set; }
    public byte Age { get; set; }
}
```

Create equality comparer:

```
public class PersonComaparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
            return true;

        if ((x == null && y != null)
            || (x != null && y == null))
            return false;

        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return 0;

        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use them to compare lists:

```
List<Person> ListA = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 1, FullName = "Someone" }
};

List<Person> ListB = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Id = 1 },
    new Person { Id = 2 }
};

PersonComaparer comparer = new PersonComaparer();
ListB = ListA
    .Intersect(ListB, comparer)
    .Union(ListB, comparer)
    .ToList();
```

The result will be:

```
Id  |   Full name
1       Someone
2       null
```

Answer (score 0):

I compared my answer below to Bapaiah Malasani's `join` solution using 10,000 items. My solution consistently took six seconds or more. His was consistently 10ms or less. Ouch. I have to go back and look at a whole ton of code I've written.

---

Should you use an `IEqualityComparer<Item>`? I would, because you're probably going to have lots and lots of code like this. Write this once and use it forever:

```
public class ItemComparer: IEqualityComparer<Item>
{
    public bool Equals(Item i1, Item i2)
    {
        if(i1 == null && i2 == null) return true;
        if(i1 == null ^ i2 ==null) return false;
        return(i1 == i2 || i1.Id == i2.Id);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Item item)
    {
        return item != null ? item.Id.GetHashcode() : 0;
    }
}
```

Then you could wrap this whole thing up in a function which makes it easier to read. With a series of `Linq` statements it might not be clear what your intent is. But a function with a clear name helps:

```
IEnumerable<T> ReplaceMatchingItems<T>(IEnumerable<T> discardFrom,
    IEnumerable<T> replaceWith,
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
    {
        //prevent multiple enumerations
        var discardFromArray = discardFrom as T[] ?? discardFrom.ToArray();
        var replacements = replaceWith.Where(item => discardFromArray.Contains(item, comparer)).ToArray();
        var newList = discardFromArray.Except(replacements, comparer).ToList();
        newList.AddRange(replacements);
        return newList;
    }
```

Now, the original function you wanted looks like this:

```
var listWithReplacements = ReplaceMatchingItems(ListB, ListA, new ItemComparer());
```

It looks like more code at first, but the `IEqualityComparer` is going to save you a lot of time down the road. And when someone sees a function call like `ReplaceMatchingItems` they're more likely to understand what the code is doing rather than just looking at a bunch of Linq queries.

Comment: You also have *bunch of Linq queries*, but wrapped in a method. I think wrapping it in a method is a good idea, but it might as well contain the "outer join" (GroupJoin) from another answer. The outer join will perform much better than your code that iterates sequences multiple times.

Comment: Yes, you have the same queries either way. The difference is you don't have to see them and figure out what they're doing when you read the calling function. You just see the function call. So if you don't care about the details of that function you don't have to read them. Then in the place where all those queries are, it's easy to tell what they're doing because they're in a function with a name that describes them.

Comment: I like the left join solution. If you say it performs better I'm inclined to take your word for it. But now I'm curious so maybe I'll run some tests. In my environment the difference in performance wouldn't matter, but it might to someone else.

Comment: I tested side-by-side with 10,000 items. Not extremely scientific, but revealing enough. My method was consistently around 6-8 seconds. The method using the join was consistently < *10 ms*. Wow. That's not splitting  hairs.