# C# update object in list

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I have a repository with a `public List<someView> list;`
Is it not possible to get an item with linq like this and just update/replace the whole object so the object in the list is updated globally right away?

```
...
var item = list.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id== viewModel.Id);
if (item != null)
{
    item = viewModel;
}
...
```

Comment: You setting the **reference** `item` to a new object, not the object that `item` originally referenced. This is how reference objects work. If you want to replace the item in the list, you need to remove and re-add it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace list item in best way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188966/how-to-replace-list-item-in-best-way)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No because `item` is just a local variable, but you can use the indexer of the list:

```
int index = list.FindIndex(m => m.Id == viewModel.Id);
if(index >= 0)
    list[index] = viewModel;
```

Comment: So you are the FGITW over a duplicate question 3 years after. I bet You didn't sleep for 3 years, waiting for someone to dupe this question!

Comment: Actually looked abit on previous questions about this but they where so complicated and alot of them where just updating single properties ;)

Comment: @DragandDrop: oh, indeed, you're right. That's why i need another coffee