# replacing multiple words in a string with multiple words

Tags: c#

So what I'm trying to do is I have a list

```
List<string> words = new List<string>();
            words.AddRange(new string[]{ "list of words", "i want to replace" })
```

and now I want to take text from a textbox and search for the words from the list "words" and replace all of them with the same text they are + something, Sorry if this is confusing or poorly explained but I did my best and thanks for all the help! :D

Comment: Can you show us some examples of what you are trying to achieve - before and after.

Comment: it seems that you need a different structure to hold your replacement mapping. It seems for me that your "list of words" is a **single** string. I guess what you actually want is a pairing of word and replacement. a `Dictionay<string, string>` would be a much better option here

Comment: I suppose you are trying to do some thing similar to this.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188966/how-to-replace-list-item-in-best-way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188966/how-to-replace-list-item-in-best-way)

Comment: It would be useful if you show what your string looks like before and what you want it to look like after.

Comment: do you want only whole words replaced? or also if the word is part of another one? like replace `"Text"`  with `"TextSuffix"` in `"TextBox"` which would result in `"TextSuffixBox"`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to achieve something like:

```
string textboxString = "Text from Textbox";
List<string> words = new List<string>();
words.Add("Text");

foreach(string word in words)
{
    textboxString = textboxString.Replace(word, word + " + something");
}
```

You could also use `Regex.Replace();`

Comment: `string.Replace()` returns a new string, seeing as `String` is immutable. Your code doesn't do anything in the end.

Comment: sorry, now changed

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand your question you want to add something to certain words. If you want that something to change depending on the word you will need a Dictionary (well... need is a strong word)

```
    string textboxString = "Text from Textbox";
    Dictionary<string, string> words = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    words.Add("Text", "Something");
    words.Add("from", "SomethingElse");
    
    foreach (var key in words)
        textboxString = textboxString.Replace(key.Key, key.Key + key.Value);
```

this should give you:

```
"TextSomething fromSomethingElse TextSomethingbox"
```

Comment: "TextSomethingbox" this replacement is probably not intended and would need some clarification by the author. But you made a very good case!

Comment: That might be right:-) Originally I had flipped the search, but the I reread the question. My original answer was: foreach(string s in textboxString.split(''')) ect and so it looped though the words in the textbox and matched them into the dic.