# How to replace new object into exiting object list<> with same ID object?

Tags: c#

Suppose i have `List<person> personlist`
with 3 items like

```
{ ID=1, name="manish"}, {ID=2, name="jon"}, {Id=3, name="david"}
```

now i want to replace existing item:

```
{ID=2, name="jon"}
```

with new item

```
{ID=2, name="Vijay"}
```

I need to do this because i have changed object with more then 50 properties.

Comment: If it's a `List<MyType>`, you'd need to remove one item and insert the new one. Please can you edit your question with actual C# code to demonstrate the type, the list and the substitute object?

Comment: You have displayed json.... is json part of this question ?

Comment: @TheGeneral I think this is meant to be the initialisation of a person object. Layzily writte... correct me if I am wrong Manish

Comment: first use `RemoveAt` then `Insert`

Comment: I suggest you take a look at this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17188966/how-to-replace-list-item-in-best-way/17189025

Comment: is the order important? does it have to be replaced at the same position?

Answer (score 4):

Without reorganizing the `List` with `Remove` and `Insert`. You could use [`FindIndex`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.findindex?view=netcore-3.1) and efficiently update the reference with the `Indexer`

> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the
> specified predicate, and returns the zero-based index of the first
> occurrence within the entire `List<T>`.

```
var list = new List<Something>()
{
   new Something() {Id = 1, Name = "bob"},
   new Something() {Id = 2, Name = "tom"},
   new Something() {Id = 3, Name = "frank"},
};

var index = list.FindIndex(x => x.Id == 2);
list[index] = new Something() {Id = 2, Name = "doug"};

foreach (var item in list)
   Console.WriteLine($"{item.Id} : {item.Name}");
```

**Output**

```
1 : bob
2 : doug
3 : frank
```

If you didn't want to entirely replace the item, you could just update a *Property*

```
var result = list.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == 2); 

if(result != null)
    result.Name = "SomethingElse";
```

Answer (score 1):

first, remove the item at index
then you need to insert the new item, if the removed item is the last item then you need to use `Add` to insert, if not the last item then use `Insert`

```
var list = ...
var item = ...
var index = 1;

list.RemoveAt(index);
if(list.Count == index) {
    list.Add(item);
} else {
    list.Insert(index , item);
}
```

Comment: you have an object as an input not the index!

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the property without replacing the entire item...

if you need to find the index first then do it anyway you like, for example:

```
var index = List.FindIndex(s => s.Id == 2);
```

than you could do something like this:

```
if (index >= 0) //index found
{
    List[index].Name == "New Value";
}
```

you don't have to create an entire new "person" and assign it to the list,
you can also modify existing ones... unless you set the name property in the "person" class to only be set during initialization...